# Query regarding regular expression

Tags: java, regex

hi I have a string like this:

```
String s = "@Path(\"/BankDBRestService/customerExist(String")\";
```

I want to make that string as

```
@Path("/BankDBRestService/customerExist")
```

I tried this:

```
String foo = s.replaceAll("[(](.*)", "");
```

i am getting output as

```
@Path
```

can anyone please provide me the reqular expression to make this work

Comment: Please escape your quotes inside the string literal. And it seems you have unbalanced parenthesis there. Is that a mistake?

Comment: oops sorry, i just copied output string to String s to demonstrate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
String s = "@Path(\"/BankDBRestService/customerExist(String\")";
String res = s.replaceAll("[(]([a-zA-Z_])+", "");
System.out.println(res);
```

Output : `@Path("/BankDBRestService/customerExist")`

If your string is `"@Path(\"/BankDBRestService/customerExist(String)\")"` i.e. with closed parenthesis then use regex `[(]([a-zA-Z_])+[)]`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String foo = s.replaceAll("(.*)\\(.*\\)", "$1");
```